# Understanding Java Pass by Value

Tags: java, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

i went through several post in stackoverflow and googled other good sites to understand the concepts of java pass by value..

my doubt goes as below.

```
Dog someDog = new Dog("FOO"); //mem location 42
foo(someDog);
someDog.setName("FIFI"); // false

    foo(Dog newDog){
      newDog.name.equals("FOO"); //true
      newDog = new Dog("FIFI");  // create a new DOG object mem location 72. my doubt here
      newDog.name.equals("FIFI"); //true
    }
```

so as above in the line `newDog = new Dog("FIFI");` my understanding goes new DOG object is created at mem location 72 and assigned to another Dog location object at mem location 42.

what does it means? at the background..

Regards
Punith.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Java "pass-by-reference"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference)

Comment: yes it is.. but what is the so as above in the line newDog = new Dog("FIFI"); my understanding goes new DOG object is created at mem location 72 and assigned to another Dog location object at mem location 42.   what does it mean ???

Comment: *and assigned to another Dog location object at mem location 42.*...Why? how you come to this conclusion?

Comment: @VishalK, i am quoting it as an example memory address. like Foo was initially created a mem location 42 and later in foo method we have assigned a value to this reference, a new Dog object created at 72. my question was why there was no difference when the value(reference address) changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void foo(Dog newDog){
    newDog.name.equals("FOO"); //true
    newDog = new Dog("FIFI");  // create a new DOG object mem location 72. my doubt here
    newDog.name.equals("FIFI"); //true
}
```

Here `newDog` is a local variable to that method. When you call that method and pass `someDog`, the value of `someDog` (which is a reference to a `Dog` object) is copied into `newDog`. So now you have 2 references pointing to the same object. That's why the first line evaluates to `true`.

After you execute

```
newDog = new Dog("FIFI");
```

the variable `newDog` references the newly created `Dog` object. This does not change the variable `someDog` at all. So now, you have 2 variables, each pointing to a different `Dog` object.

After the method is done, the `newDog` variable disappears, and the newly created `Dog` object has no more reference pointing to it, so it becomes eligible for garbage collection.

The code posted in the method doesnt't change any attributes of the object referenced by `someDog`, and it can never switch the object referenced by `someDog`

That's why

```
someDog.setName("FIFI"); // is false
```

Understood?

Answer (score 5):

One picture is worth thousand words, so here is what is going on:

[image: Variable to object diagrams]

As you can see, the two variables `someDog` in the caller and `newDog` in the `foo` reference the same object initially. After the assignment, they reference different objects, explaining the behavior that you see: since `Dog` is passed by reference, and because you created a new `Dog` rather than modifying the existing one, `newDog` becomes unrelated to `someDog` after the assignment.

Note that if you modified the existing dog, the picture would have been different: if you did `newDog.setName("FIFI");` inside `foo`, rather than `newDog = new Dog("FIFI");`, the results would be different: the diagram would still look like the middle picture, but the dog's name would have been `FIFI`.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new Dog object (FIFI) and letting the method parameter newDog reference this new object. This has no effect whatsoever on the object still referenced by someDog. So, this variable does still reference the same object. Was this what you are wondering about?